# How to prevent user go to next view when no file selected? In ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am implementing in Ruby on Rails, and have a little problem. I have a form, in which you can select a file (CSV-file), which I then can read. But if I do not have a file selected, and i click on the submit button, an error is shown. Because my CSV-reader want to read something and this is nil.
But now what i want is that when I click on the submit button, there just comes an error under the button, which tells the user he can't go to the next view, because he haven't selected a file. 
I searched for this, but nothing found similar like this. Does someone know what to do?
Thanks!

This is my form :

```
<% form_tag({:action => 'match'}, {:multipart => true}) do %>
<table">
   <tr>
     <td>
      <label for="dump_file">
        Select a CSV File :
      </label>
     </td>
     <td >
       <%= file_field_tag 'file', :size => 60%></p>
     </td>
   </tr>

 </table>
 <br/>

       <%= submit_tag 'Submit' -%>  

<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this javascript code to prevent the submission if not file selected. You should put this in public/javascripts/application.js

```
$(function(){
  $('#file_form_id').submit(function (e) {
    if ($(this).find('input[name="file"]').val() == '') { 
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('select a file');
    }     
  });
})
```

Also you would have to indicate the id of the form like this in the view:

```
<% form_tag({:action => 'match'}, {:multipart => true, :id => 'file_form_id'}) do %>
```

Comment: So how would this look like exactly in my case? because i doesn't work? Do I just have to put this beneath my code?

Comment: I copied your code exactly, and if I click on the button, the application just want to go to the next view and I keep having just the same error..

Comment: do you have a demo url I can check?